# Изменение элементов в multiset

Tags: c++

Есть мультимножество,нужно ко всем элементам прибавить чилсло,как это можно сделать,ведь элементы в multiset нельзя изменять.

Comment: я так понимаю, нужно обойтись без создания нового multiset'а и без перестроения дерева? в качестве грязного хака можно просто наплевав на константность обойти все элементы и увеличить их на 1... чисто думаю, ни как не сделать...

Comment: Ну я думаю можно сделать так прибавить допустим к первому элементу 1 ,записать его в конец, и удалить старый элемент и так далее,вот как сделать не могу допереть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

multiset<int> setplus(multiset<int> S, int num){
   multiset<int> result;
   for_each(S.begin(), S.end(), [=, &result] (int el) -> void {
    result.insert(el + num);
   });
   return result;
}

int main() {
   multiset<int> S;
   for(int i = 1;i <= 5;i++) S.insert(i);
   S = setplus(S, 1);
   for_each(S.begin(), S.end(),[] (int el) -> void {
    cout << el << "\n";
   });
}
```

Один из вариантов, просто забить все в новый мультисет.

Comment: Понял,спасибо,сейчас попробую

Comment: можете объяснить,что происходить тут
multiset<int> setplus(multiset<int> S, int num)

Comment: @Kruk, Функция возвращает новый multiset. В аргументах старый и число на которое вы увеличиваете каждый элемент. В самой функции объявляете новый multiset в цикле вставляете в него каждый элемент из старого + num и возвращаете.

Comment: Вроде понял,если что еще напишу.

Comment: [=, &result] (int el) -> void  а вот это что делает?

Comment: @Kruk, лямбда-функция

Comment: перед тем, как использовать  for_each, подумайте какие еще есть альгоритмы.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а что не так с for_each ?

Comment: многократный вызов лямбда функции,  и его  результатом  является эта функция, которую вы не используете.  Более специализированные альгоритмы ,  естественно, работают быстрее и не требуют сложных конфигураций

Answer (score 0):

То же самое, что было в первом ответе, можно выразить более эффективным кодом:

```
int main()
{    
    std::multiset<int> S, res;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            S.insert(i);
    std::transform(S.begin(), S.end(), std::inserter(res, res.end()), [](int i) {return ++i;});
    std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```